# integrate a GoogleMap with twig variables - Symfony 3

Tags: google-maps, symfony, twig

I need to integrate a google map with specific and dynamic coordinates.

I am no expert on google map, I saw there is a tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) but I have variables `latitude` and `longitude` that I setted up in my project, And I want to use it when in my back office I add a new location and the google map automatically places itself upon the location.

In this example I have an entity `Restaurant` with `latitude` and `longitude` inside it.

So I tried this kind of things:

```
<div class="{{ restaurant.name }}">
    <iframe
            src="{{ restaurant.latitude }}{{ restaurant.longitude }}"
            width="600"
            height="450"
            frameborder="0"
            style="border:0"
            allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And I didn't use any API or complicated things, I just went on GoogleMap and copied the iframe and added my `twigs` in it.

After trying that I received an error:

```
`Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Services\SlotPickerManager::createJsCommand() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Restaurant, null given, called in /var/www/html/FoodAndYou_V2/src/AppBundle/Controller/RestaurantController.php on line 123`
```

here is my `showAction` in my controller

```
public function showAction($slug, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $restaurant = $em->getRepository(Restaurant::class)->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug));
    $slotPicker = $this->get('app.slot_picker_manager');

    $slot = new Slot();
    $form = $this->createForm(SlotType::class, $slot);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $itemCreated = $slotPicker->buySlot($slot, $restaurant, $this->getUser());
        if ($itemCreated) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_basket_display_fr');
        }
    }
    $jsDisabledDays = $slotPicker->createJsCommand($restaurant);

    return $this->render('app/restaurant/restaurant.html.twig', array(
        'restaurant'        => $restaurant,
        'jsDisabledDays'    => $jsDisabledDays,
        'form'              => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

So I wonder if someone here already integrated a map with twig variables ? Because I am a bit lost with that.

thank you

Comment: Problem seems to be in controller not in template, as error says you are passing a `null` value when it expects a `Restaurant` type, in line 123 of your controller.

Comment: this is weird :/ I will copy/paste my controller section regarding this view, the line 123 is this one -> `$jsDisabledDays = $slotPicker->createJsCommand($restaurant);`

Comment: verify that `$restaurant` entity exists in database, maybe your `$slug` value is not correct. debug it, f.e: `var_dump($restaurant)`. And always check that doctrine retrieve a value using `if (!$restaurant) {//entity does not exists, redirect to somewhere}`

Comment: okay I will try that tonight, thank you for the advice. I will update or respond you in a day max.